# Necessary adjustments when running react app on amplify server instead of local machine

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I developed a reactjs web app which I want to make accessible via federated login (i.e. logging in with Google credentials). Therefor I created an Amplify project and followed the instructions of the [aws tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js) for Social sign-in (OAuth).

It all works fine when I run the app locally. In my amplify project I tried to include the frontend code by linking it to my github repo. I was able to deploy the app successfully before implementing federated login. Once I did that - after logging in to my google account - I get a redirection error. It says "Localhost denied the connection". How can I change the settings such that I get redirected to the correct url? Below you can see the aws-export.js. I tried changing redirectSignin/Signout (comments) I still get same error though. How can I make it work?

```
    const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-2:203de857-b72c-41e1-a349-e8689e1d7b88",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-2_7Hqae0xMa",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "fmb3jgl1ojmgs9655i2cona66",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "cvhfederated23782f2e-23782f2e-dev.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com",
        // "domain": "cvhfederated23782f2e-23782f2e-final.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "phone",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "redirectSignOut": "http://localhost:3000/",
        // "redirectSignIn": "https://final.dw4tcn2vagyv6.amplifyapp.com/",
        // "redirectSignOut": "https://final.dw4tcn2vagyv6.amplifyapp.com/",
        "responseType": "code"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue in the past and opted to update the configuration values at runtime.

```js
import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';

awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignIn = `${window.location.origin}/`;
awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignOut = `${window.location.origin}/`;

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

Comment: Oh I like this approach a lot.

Comment: Please do I place this code

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js#amazon-cognito-user-pool-setup

Basically, this kind of configuration needs to be handled in code. Put in both the localhost and production signin/signout redirects separated by a comma (`,`).

Then, after importing your `aws-exports`, split the redirect values e.g., `awsConfig.oauth.redirectSignIn.split(",")`

Finally, use `window.location.hostname` to conditionally choose the correct redirect urls e.g.,

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === "localhost" ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === "[::1]" ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);
```